# Searching for phrases in a block of text

Tags: pattern-matching, text, searching

One could call this a pattern finding question with dictionary (or WolframAlpha) lookup, but let me give you some background first.

I have a couple of friends who are trying to improve their English listening skills by watching TV shows in English, with English subtitles. I have access to the subtitles in text format which I can import and process as I like. Now it is easy to pick out common words from a list of words using something like `Tally`, but what I would like to do is more complicated. I want to pick out phrases (and perhaps some longer or slang-like words) that a non-native speaker may not recognize. I understand I need some sort of a lookup for this, and I thought of using WolframAlpha's `Phrase:WordData` pod, but it doesn't show up for every word, and didn't exactly do what I really wanted. I'll provide an example block of text below if anybody would like to go ahead and try it using whatever method they would like.

```
myStr = "Wow that must have been an awful result. That was not even close! People didn't even find out until they reviewed the footage.";
myStrList = StringCases[myStr, WordCharacter ..]
```

And this gives

> {"Wow", "that", "must", "have", "been", "an", "awful", "result", "That", "was", "not", "even", "close", "People", "didn", "t", "even", "find", "out", "until", "they", "reviewed", "the", "footage"}

Now I'd like an output that might look like something like

> {"awful", "not even close", "find out", "reviewed", "footage"}

I know this is rather vague, but I think determining search patterns and how the search would be executed would be a good start.

Answer (score 4):

You need decent frequency data, which is hard to come by. [This data](http://nlp.cs.nyu.edu/wikipedia-data/) is pretty good; it was collected from Wikipedia. I don't have it installed on this machine and the file is gigantic, so I'll show you how to do it using crappy data from [here](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/).

First let's clean up the text.

```
myStr="Wow that must have been an awful result. That was not even close! People didn't even find out until they reviewed the footage.";
phrase=Fold[
  StringSplit,
  myStr,
  { RegularExpression["[.!?]"], RegularExpression["\\s+"] } ]
```

> {{Wow,that,must,have,been,an,awful,result},{That,was,not,even,close},{People,didn't,even,find,out,until,they,reviewed,the,footage}}

Alright. Out of loyalty, one (abominably slow) option is

```
rare=
  With[{
    freq=WolframAlpha[#,{{"Frequency:WordData",1},"ComputableData"}]},
    If[
      MatchQ[freq,_Missing],True,
      StringCases[
        freq[[1,1]],
        d:DigitCharacter.. :> ToExpression[d]][[1]] //If[#>2000,True,False]]]&;

Cases[phrase, s_String?rare, Infinity]
```

> {"Wow", "been", "People", "didn't", "reviewed", "footage"}

Doing it with our own data (emphatically, use the better data):

```
freqData = Import["...\\en-2012.zip", {"en.txt"}];
freqs=
  Append[
    MapAt[
      ToExpression,
      Fold[ StringSplit, freqData, {"\n"," "..} ],
      {All,2} ] ,
    _String->0];
freqs[[All,2]] = Power[Rescale@freqs[[All,2]], 1/3] ;
freqs = Dispatch[ Rule@@@ freqs ] ;

Cases[phrase,w_String/;(ToLowerCase[w]/.freqs)<.1,Infinity]
```

> {"result", "didn't", "reviewed", "footage"}

The data I recommended includes "n-grams" up to 7. Those are sequences of words, for example "not even close". You would test for them in much the same way by chopping up the text into segments of appropriate length:

```
phrase/.l:{__String}:>ReplaceList[l,{___,a_,b_,c_,___}:>{a,b,c}]
```

> {{{Wow,that,must},{that,must,have},{must,have,been},{have,been,an},{been,an,awful},{an,awful,result}},{{That,was,not},{was,not,even},{not,even,close}},{{People,didn't,even},{didn't,even,find},{even,find,out},{find,out,until},{out,until,they},{until,they,reviewed},{they,reviewed,the},{reviewed,the,footage}}}

You probably want to `IgnoreCase` and may want to make other decisions concerning, for example, punctuation.

See also [this corpus](http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/OpenSubtitles2013.php), built on movie subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

Think about making a watch-list per say, to run through a string to weed out words you add to your list.

Im sure someone can put some shine on this dull code but it works for me.

```
myStr="Wow that must have been an awful result. That was not even close! People didn't even find out until they reviewed the footage.";
watchlist={"awful","worst","dont even","not even close"};
DeleteCases[Table[StringCases[myStr,watchlist[[i]]],{i,1,Length[watchlist],1}],{}]
```